Allocate a 3D matrix from sparse data
I have data in the form of a pandas DataFrame generated from an external program. The data are provided as as a "sparse matrix" with temperatures at coordinates (x,y,z) (see code snippet below). It's not immediately obvious, but not all (x,y,z)-points have a value (although most combinations do, so this is not really a "sparse" matrix). For example the values for (0,-0.25.0) and (5.1,0.0,-0.21) are missing in the list below. In order to work with the data I'd like to rearrange it as a 3D matrix (numpy.ndarray). I was thinking of sparse matrices, but the only ways I've found to allocate and densify a matrix like this is by using csr_matrix from scipy.sparse, which only works for 2D matrices. That means that I have to stack 2D matrices in a for loop which I then densify using numpy.expand_dims. It works, but it is terribly slow. I'm sure there's a better and faster way to do this.
In []: print(data)
Out[]:
          x     y     z        T
0      0.05 -0.25  0.00  1516.61
1      0.10 -0.25  0.00  1572.59
2      0.15 -0.25  0.00  1590.58
3      0.20 -0.25  0.00  1615.54
4      0.25 -0.25  0.00  1629.69
    ...   ...   ...      ...
18647  4.25  0.00 -0.21  1813.54
18648  4.30  0.00 -0.21  1821.97
18649  4.35  0.00 -0.21  1814.80
18650  4.40  0.00 -0.21  1822.60
18651  4.45  0.00 -0.21  1813.72

[18652 rows x 4 columns]

In []: x = data.x.unique()

In []: y = data.y.unique()

In []: z = data.z.unique()

In []: print(len(x)*len(y)*len(z))
Out[]: 25894

Solution attempt (some numbers are hardcoded for this particular example):
def get_dense_matrix(data,tol=1e-6):
    x = np.arange(data.x.min(),data.x.max()+2*tol,0.05)
    y = np.arange(data.y.min(),data.y.max()+2*tol,0.05)
    z = np.arange(data.z.min(),data.z.max()+2*tol,0.05)
    T = np.zeros((len(x),len(y),len(z)))
    for i,_z in enumerate(z):
        zdata = data[np.abs(data.z-_z)<tol]
        row = np.round((zdata.x+zdata.x.min())*20)
        col = np.round((zdata.y+zdata.y.min())*20)
        T_ = zdata['T']
        A = csr_matrix((T_, (row, col)), shape=(len(x), len(y)))
        A = A.toarray()
        T[:,:,i] = A
    return np.expand_dims(T,0)


Can you try the function I wrote as part of this answer, which is called dataset_to_dense()? If seems like it's solving the same problem. You could call it as dataset_to_dense(data, ['x', 'y', 'z'], 'T').

Are the inter-point distances consistent within each axis? Can you show these distances in your question? x is 0.05 but y and z are unclear.

Can  you directly assign z values to T?   Something like T[row, col, i] = T_  Once you have the row/col indices, those should simply tell you where to put the z values, without needing to go through csr.

@NickODell Thank you! That worked fine, and was about 6-7 times faster than what I had before,

@hpaulj Yes, it's a regular (cartesian) grid, so indeed that could also be a valid option. I'll try that solution too.
